Does Ubuntu support the stylus on LG Gram 2-in-1 Touchscreen?
I'm considering an LG Gram 2-in-1 Touchscreen laptop with stylus to run Ubuntu.  I want to use the stylus for whiteboard sketching (not art work).
Has anyone gotten Ubuntu to run on this laptop?  If so how is the support for the stylus?  Also what drawing or whiteboard software works well?  I don't need collaborative whiteboard functionality.  Just local sketching.

Would the people voting to close this question tell me what the problem is?  Is there a better forum to ask about Ubuntu compatibility on  specific hardware?
